# How do I update a second table from a cte so that it works reliably

Tags: t-sql, sql-update, common-table-expression, partitioning

It would be great to get some advice on the following Robot performance data problem that is driving me crazy! We have 23 Robots in 5 Facilities and Spot data (placement and pickup locations) from all of them is collected into one big table. I have two tables #Temp2 and #Temp2d as follows:

```
#Temp2
 ID   Spot LastDiff
76544  21    23
76545  21     0
76546  23    21
76547  23     0
76548  21    35
76549  23    21
76550  21    23
76551  23    21

#Temp2d
IDmin  Spot LastDiff
76544   21    23
76546   23    21
76548   21    23
76549   23    21
76550   21    23
76551   23    21
```

The table #Temp2d is derived from #Temp2 and records the individual changes in Spot number (repeat Spot numbers have been removed). (The 90,000 record Spot number data is partitioned by two other columns not shown, FacilityName and Robot). 
I'm then adding a new column "LastDiff"  to #Temp2 to hold the last different value of Spot before it changed. To update the LastDiff column of #Temp2 the following update query is used:

```
;with cte_1 as
        (
        select t1.IDmin, t1.spot, t1.lastDiff
        from
            (
            select 
                IDmin
                , spot
                , LAG(spot,1,0) OVER(PARTITION BY FacilityName, Robot ORDER BY FacilityName, Robot) AS lastDiff

            from #Temp2d
            ) t1
        )  
        update #Temp2 set #Temp2.lastDiff = cte_1.lastDiff
        from cte_1
        where #Temp2.ID = cte_1.IDmin
```

The problem is that in the 90,000 row dataset around 30 values of LastDiff in #Temp2 are wrong, as shown in row 76,548 in the above #Temp2 table. There does not seem to be any pattern to the errors, they occur randomly throughout the dataset. Any assistance is resolving this problem would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Might be, that the `ORDER BY` in your `LAG()`'s `OVER`-clause is not correct. You must use a column to order which ensures the sorting you need...

Comment: ha ha thanks so much - talk about overlooking the obvious! adding IDmin to the partition order-by did the trick: LAG(spot,1,0) OVER(PARTITION BY FacilityName, Robot ORDER BY FacilityName, Robot, IDmin) AS lastDiff